Use Android native SpeechRecognizer and record session
I am trying to build an application in Android that uses the Google library SpeechRecognizer for retrieving speech to text on device for free. I also want to record the user while he speaks, so I can have in text and in an audio file.
The issue is that when I try to record using the microphone while the SpeechRecognizer is active, the SpeechRecognizer breaks and stops working.
When I am not trying to record using MediaRecorder/AudioRecorder it works like a charm. As soon as I start recording it breaks.
What are the solutions for this problem? Is it possible to make this work?
I am initializing the SpeechRecognizer service like so:
val recognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createOnDeviceSpeechRecognizer(context)

recognizer.setRecognitionListener{
  // deal with recognized events (partial and complete)
  ...
}

recognizer.startListening(
 Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
  .putExtra(EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM)
  .putExtra(EXTRA_LANGUAGE, ENGLISH_LOCALE)
  .putExtra(EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, true)
  .putExtra(EXTRA_REQUEST_WORD_CONFIDENCE, true)
  .putExtra(EXTRA_BIASING_STRINGS, biasString.toTypedArray())
)


You may want to identify which version of Android are you targeting/testing on and how you are testing (emulator or device with make/model/OS version). Found and may be relevant: https://developer.android.com/media/platform/sharing-audio-input
